# QFileDialog issue with special character

Tags: c++, qt, special-characters, qfiledialog

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QFileDialog>
#include <QDebug>

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QFileDialog dlg;
    dlg.setAcceptMode(QFileDialog::AcceptSave);
    if (dlg.exec()) {
        qDebug() << dlg.selectedFiles();
    }
    return app.exec();
}
```

With this code we can can create `QFileDialog`. The problem is that it doesn't recoginize some special characters which can be typed in its "File name" entry:

1) For `"""` save button become disabled so I cant save file with name `"""`

2) For `"aaa` it prints `aaa`

3) For `\"aaa` it again prints `aaa`

4) For `aaaa"eee` it prints `eee`

5) For `\"` save button is enabled but it does nothing when clicked.

I am using Linux. Does anyone konw the solution for this issue?

Comment: underlying file system may not allow those characters

Comment: I can create files with name `"` using `touch \"` command

Comment: @Ashot The various Windows subsystems / tools are such a complete mess with regard to what format they require a path name to meet. Some support this, others support that. I find it's best to stay away from fancy characters in path names. :-\

EDIT: Never mind, you specifically stated you're working on Linux, not Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason of such behavior could be that `"` character used as a file names separator in the QFileDialog's line edit. I.e. you can write something like `"file1" "file2"` to open multiple files. For better understanding on what is going on in this dialog, you can take a look in Qt sources, especially in `QFileDialogPrivate::typedFiles()` function (qfiledialog.cpp), where your input is split by `"`:

```
QStringList tokens = editText.split(QLatin1Char('\"'));
```